# How to override the behavior of the volume buttons in an Android application?

Tags: android

I'd like to use the volume buttons for something else in my Android application. The Dolphin browser does this I am told. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I imagine it looks something like this:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{ 
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) { 
       // Do your thing 
       return true;
   } else {
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Sweet. You have to 'return true;' after doing your thing to suppress the phone's default volume behavior.

Comment: Also to completely suppress the default behavior you should also catch the events and return true in an onKeyUp() override.

Comment: Or you could override dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) method.

Comment: The dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) method is the better choice. If I use onKeyDown(...) it still gets through to the AudioManager and I get the following debug Message even though I am returning true: "AudioHardwareQSD(3394): AudioHardware pcm playback is going to standby."

Comment: What is the difference between the onKeyDown() and onKeyUp() Methods ?

Answer (score 37):

in your activity,

```
 @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Using onKeyDown or onKeyUp still gives the default sound of changing the volume.