# MediaPlayer.setVolume() function doesn't seem to work

Tags: android

I need to set media volume to **MAX** in my app to play a buzzer.
I am trying to do it by using `media.setVolume()` function but it doesn't seem to work.

I have already tried

```
mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
```

I have also tried

```
int MAX_VOLUME = 1000;
final float volume = (float) (1 - (Math.log(MAX_VOLUME - 999) / Math.log(MAX_VOLUME)));
mediaPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);
```

None of the above worked for me.

Somebody pls help me on how to set media volume to full **using `MediaPlayer.setVolume(float, float)` function**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`MediaPlayer.setVolume(float, float)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setVolume(float,%20float)) sets the volume of the given MediaPlayer instance. This volume is `1.0f` (max) by default. It doesn't change the global media volume which is what I wanted to accomplish originally.

I found a solution that simply sets the global media volume.

**Useful Remark:** I found many answers on stackoverflow.com for setting **max volume level** or **changing volume**, most of them used **alarm stream (STREAM_ALARM)** to do so. I think using alarm stream would not be a good option if you are playing audio casually.

The global volume of a stream type (music in this case) can be changed using the following code.

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
```

Now, play your media object as a Music Stream :

```
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Make sure that you request `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` permission in your application's manifest.

```
<uses-permission
  android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

**Note:** This only sets **Media (Music) Volume** to the max. To set other Volumes like **Ringer**, use **STREAM_RING**.

Thanks, @MrTristan for your advice, it was really helpful.

Comment: this is bad practice,unless you aim to effect the entire device stream, the alternative is to use the MediaPlayer object to effect the stream within the given bounds for the application.

Comment: hey, @ashu I want to modify the code so that even if the volume down key is pressed it should the volume shouldn't be affected. how do i do it?

Comment: @RaunakPandey this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367484/how-to-override-the-behavior-of-the-volume-buttons-in-an-android-application

Answer (score 2):

make sure you've got MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS set as a permission you request in your app if that's the type of volume you're looking to set.

Comment: Nothing happened even after asking for this permission.

Answer (score 1):

> Note that the passed volume values are raw scalars in range 0.0 to 1.0

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume(float, float)

Why don't you try just using `mp.setVolume(1.0, 1.0)`.

Comment: You should use this instead: `mp.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f)`

Answer (score 0):

`setVolume()` doesn't work properly, so you should set stream volume by AudioManager.
This one has a bad effect too and it is that you change the entire stream volume of the user device!
And user doesn't like this, so you should change it back to the default value.

But how?!

Define your AudioManager:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Store current volume and set stream value to its Maximum value:

```
int currentVolume = Objects.requireNonNull(am).getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION), 0);
```

Define `AudioAttributes.Builder` and set the stream type for it:

```
AudioAttributes.Builder audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder();
audioAttributes.setLegacyStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
```

Set audio attributes for your `MediaPlayer` before calling `prepare()` or `prepareAsync()`:

```
mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes.build());
```

Finally set a on completion listener for mediaPlayer and change the volume to its default:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.release();
                    am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, currentVolume, 0);
                }
            });
```

Finish! You could handle the problem. :)

Comment: Doesn't work for Chromebooks and headunits