# How to override (or at least listen to) bluetooth headset volume buttons on android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, keypress, headset, avrcp

I would like to control my app with a headset keys (volume +, middle key, volume -).

I have no problem detecting media keys:

- play/pause, triggered by click on middle
- next/previous, triggered by volume buttons long press

I do have a problem detecting (and ideally intercepting) everything else. I am especially interested in volume keys.

**!!** Solutions with **onKeyDown** or listening to **MEDIA_BUTTON** or **listening to volume changes** (e.g. via AudioService) work with phone volume keys, but not with bluetooth volume keys **!!**

More info:
(just as info) In activity on onKeyDown I do not see headset key presses (it only picks up clicks on phone volume rocker).

I cannot infer clicks from volume changes, as there is no trigger if the device is at max/min volume. Also the volume dialog does not show up if I try to set above max volume with headset, as it does with phone volume buttons.

In debugger, the only thing that happens upon vol+ on max volume is some action reported from avrcp in debug mode:

```
07:04:08.220 7106-7250/? I/BluetoothAvrcpServiceJni: btavrcp_volume_change_callback
07:04:08.220 7106-30330/? V/Avrcp: MSG_NATIVE_REQ_VOLUME_CHANGE: volume=127 ctype=13
07:04:08.281 5937-13180/? I/EDMNativeHelperService: isAVRCPProfileEnabled
07:04:08.285 7106-7250/? I/BluetoothAvrcpServiceJni: btavrcp_volume_change_callback
07:04:08.285 7106-30330/? V/Avrcp: MSG_NATIVE_REQ_VOLUME_CHANGE: volume=127 ctype=15
```

How could I get these events with my service? Or is there any useful alternative to detect such headset clicks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override the behavior of the volume buttons in an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367484/how-to-override-the-behavior-of-the-volume-buttons-in-an-android-application)

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17398781/6549598

Comment: I checked both links (and many other) before posting. I wrote in my question that **onKeyDown** or listening to volume changes does not work for me. Both solutions would work (although first one not for Service) for phone volume rocker, but not for bluetooth headset.

Comment: @Jure S, any luck? did you found a solution?

Comment: No. During testing I also realized that overriding volume buttons would not be justified from UX perspective. You'd have to have very strong reasons to go down that way + it does not seem to be (easily) possible.